# Using dot product of non-normalized vectors to project a point onto a line?

Tags: vector, 2d, dot-product

I'm trying to determine whether a line intersects a circle, and to do that I'm trying to first calculate whether a point (circle center) is within the bounds of the line, when projected onto the line.

I found an example of that being done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ercang/ornh3594/1/), but I'm having trouble understanding part of it. It creates two vectors, from the one end of the line to the point, and from one end of the line to the other. That's fine.

```
vec2 vecToPoint = point - lineA;
vec2 vecLine = lineB - lineA;
```

But then it takes the dot product of these two vectors and divides them, using the result as an offset along the line for the projected point.

```
float coef = dot(vecToPoint,vecLine) / dot(vecLine,vecLine);
return vec2( lineA.x + (coef * vecLine.x), lineA.y + (coef * vecLine.y) );
```

This is the part I don't understand. I've done dot products of normalized vectors to get the angle, but I've never seen non-normalized vectors in a dot product before, much less dividing the results.

Can someone explain to me how this is working? What is it doing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the projection of a point onto a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330618/finding-the-projection-of-a-point-onto-a-line)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix_transformations/lin_trans_examples/v/introduction-to-projections) that explains the math behind this. Makes sense now!

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Even if the video explains it, an answer replicates the steps so that others can find that information _in the answer_ even if it links out to the source of that information.