# Finding the projection of a point onto a line

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I am not very good at math and I am aware that there are other people asking similar things to me but I don't really understand the explanations.

My problem is: I have a line given by 2 points A,B and another point X, I would like to find a point on the line AB that represents the projection of the point X on the line AB.

For example lets say I have the coordinates for **A** and **B** and for the point **C**, I would like to find the coordinate for **D** as per the figure below:

```
A---D-------------B
         
    C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make vectors:

```
AB = B - A
AC = C - A
```

Or in coordinates:

```
AB = (abx, aby)
AC = (acx, acy)
```

Where:

```
abx = B.x - A.x
aby = B.y - A.y
acx = C.x - A.x
acy = C.y - A.y
```

The simplest form of projection of **C** onto **A—B**, using the dot product, is:

```
AD = AB * (AB dot AC) / (AB dot AB)
D = (dx, dy) = A + AD
```

Or in coordinates:

```
coeff = (abx*acx + aby*acy) / (abx*abx+aby*aby)
dx = A.x + abx * coeff
dy = A.y + aby * coeff
```

Comment: By `dot` you mean the dot product?

Comment: @MBo the edits made the answer _far_ easier to understand, without changing anything about the approach you wrote. I would recommend not reverting them, as easy to understand answers are why folks come here for help. (at the very least, keep your vectors uppercase, but dimensions lowercase, which the standard convention for vectors vs scalars)

Comment: @Mike Variable names were inconsistent with text description - dx,dy for AB direction, while D is projection point, `cx` for AC component might be tangled with `C.x` etc, so I cancelled the second edit. Will edit.